# unable to use autofilter to show dates before 2014 excel c#

Tags: c#, excel, autofilter

I am trying to use 'AutoFilter' to show all the cells that are before 2014. But I don't know how to do that. I was able to show only "01/01/2014" because my code chose in the 'AutoFilter' equals and I want is before.

This is my code:

```
range1 = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1:" + GetExcelColumnName(Globals.cl) + "1", Type.Missing);
range1.AutoFilter(cHireDate, "01/01/2014");
```

I tried to find on the web but I was unable to find something similar.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a Less Than:

```
range1.AutoFilter(cHireDate, "<01/01/2014");
```

Comment: Thanks That do the trick :) (i didn't know that you can do < inside the string)

Comment: Yes - the excel interop uses very similar syntax to the Excel and excel vba functions. You can verify some of these types of things by recording macros in excel!